# Else statement only if checked through entire array

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I want my program to only print the "else statement" once, only after the for loop have already searched through my length of the "orderProduct" array.

What I currently have:

```
do
{
    System.out.print("Enter Order: "); 
    userOrder = in.next();

    for(int i=0; i<orderProduct.length; i++)
    {
        if(userOrder.equals(orderProduct[i].code))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Amount: ");
            userQuantity = in.nextInt();
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, invalid order.");
        }
    }
}
while(!userOrder.equals("0"));
```

This code always execute the "else statement" after it checked the first element of the array. Is there any way to print it only if the for loop has gone through the entire array?

Comment: you need to remove that from loop and you may need to use some flag variable for condition so that you can test outside the loop.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a **flag** within the if loop and check **if it remains unset** after the entire for loop.

```
Boolean valid = false;
for(int i=0; i<orderProduct.length; i++)
{
    if(userOrder.equals(orderProduct[i].code))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Amount: ");
        userQuantity = in.nextInt();
        valid = true;
        break;
    }

}
if(!valid){
        System.out.println("Sorry, invalid order.");
}
```

Comment: You should also add a break in the `if` condition, to avoid iterating till the end.

Comment: your code is saying that if at lease one product code within the order is valid, then the whole order is valid. I'm not sure if that's what the author wanted to achieve.

Comment: @VladSpreys.. No this not what OP wants to achieve. He is checking the order number against all the orders stored in the array. And if it is found in the array, do the processing.

Comment: I have added the `break` back, my missunderstanding about the purpose,  but it doesnt really change anything beyond a very small speed gain, assuming the code is unique for each product.

Comment: @VladSpreys OP is searching the list for the one product code that matches, so I believe that my code achieves that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `break` [branching statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) inside `else` and not inside the `if`. alternatively change the loop to `while` with stop condition you currently have in your `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean invalidOrder = false;
do
{
    System.out.print("Enter Order: "); 
    userOrder = in.next();

    for(int i=0; i<orderProduct.length; i++)
    {
        if(userOrder.equals(orderProduct[i].code))
        {
            System.out.print("Enter Amount: ");
            userQuantity = in.nextInt();
        }
        else
        {
            invalidOrder = true;
        }
    }
}
while(!userOrder.equals("0"));

if(invalidOrder)
    System.out.println("Sorry, invalid order.");
```

Comment: you know this will have the same result, as he said he will allways go in the else tree?

Comment: but even if it´s a valid order, and the user typed in a 0.
even so it will only print invalid order, when the user has left the whole order loop

Comment: I believe the OP is seaching through the list for the one matching code. This means that it will be "invalidOrder" in N-1 of the iterations, and without the break, there is a high chance the last iteration might be invalid, even if the code was found earlier.

Answer (score 0):

try to set a condition to print the whole thing

```
do
{
System.out.print("Enter Order: "); 
userOrder = in.next();

boolean found = false;

for(int i=0; i<orderProduct.length; i++)
{
    if(userOrder.equals(orderProduct[i].code))
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Amount: ");
        userQuantity = in.nextInt();
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!found)
    System.out.println("Sorry, invalid order.");
}
while(!userOrder.equals("0"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from using a flag you can use a label.

```
FOUND: {
  for(OrderProduct op: orderProduct) {
    if(userOrder.equals(op.code)) {
        System.out.print("Enter Amount: ");
        userQuantity = in.nextInt();
        break FOUND;
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Sorry, invalid order.");
}
```

Or you can move the loop into a method and use return instead of break.

However it appears what you really want is a Map.

```
// use a map instead of a collection or an array.
Map<String, OrderProduct> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(OrderProduct op: orderProduct) map.put(op.code, op);

OrderProduct op = null;
while(op == null) {
  System.out.print("Enter Order: "); 
  String userOrder = in.next();
  OrderProduct op = map.get(userOrder);
  if (op == null) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, invalid order.");
  } else {
    System.out.print("Enter Amount: ");
    userQuantity = in.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try something like this I know question is not about maps but you can do same for Arrays as well.

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> cookieMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> cookieSet = null;

        cookieMap.put("A", "1");
        cookieMap.put("B", "2");
        cookieMap.put("C", "3");
        cookieMap.put("D", "4");
        cookieMap.put("E", "5");

        cookieSet = cookieMap.entrySet();
        Boolean valid = false;
          for (Map.Entry<String, String> cookieKeyValue : cookieSet) {
              if(cookieKeyValue.getKey().contains("H")){
                  System.out.println(cookieKeyValue.getValue());
                  System.out.println("True");
                  valid = true;
                  break;
              }
          } if (!valid) {
              System.out.println("False");
          }
     }
}
```